# Set log4j SMTPAppender field in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using slf4j with log4j to log errors in a Java desktop application by email.
Currently I use a log4j properties file to sets the fields such as username, password etc:

```
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost = smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername = example@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword = examplepass
# ...etc...
```

This works fine but I would prefer to set the password dynamically in Java code.

I have seen the method [SMTPAppender.setSMTPPassword](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html#setSMTPPassword%28java.lang.String%29) which seems to be what I want but I can't see how to get a handle on the SMTPAppender object to call that method.
I have tried the OP's snippet in [Log4j programmatically setting SMTP settings is not completely working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911622/log4j-programmatically-setting-smtp-settings-is-not-completely-working) but my logger object doesnt have a getAllAppenders() method. I assume this is because I am using slf4j loggers instead of plain log4j ones.

So, how can I set these properties in Java rather than .properties file?